# Maven - how to handle generated classes

Tags: eclipse, maven, wsdl

My dilemma is that I have my doubts regarding generated source files in maven.

I'm trying to generate some classes from a WSDL and I don't really know what is the standard way to handle the resulting source files.

- Where should I generate the .java source files? (src/main/java, src/main/generated)
- Should I include them under source control, or let them be generated after check-out
- If I don't use the src/main/java folder, how to convince Eclipse automatically to "see" those classes as source folder?
- Do I really need the .java files, or only the .class-es?

What are the best-practices regarding this issue? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks for your kind answers,
Mark

Answer (score 13):

Most of the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) plugins I've come across that generate code follow a convention of placing the generated Java source files in a sub-directory of the `target/generated-sources` folder. For an example, the [Maven 2 JAXB 2.x Plugin](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home) generates the Java sources in the `target/generated-sources/xjc` folder.

As long as the build is repeatable I don't see the need to commit the generated sources to my source code repository. So I usually configure my [Git](http://git-scm.com), [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org), [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org) or whatever I am using to ignore everything under `target`.

I usually manually edit the `.classpath` file to include the source folder for [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and I store both the `.classpath` and `.project` files in the source code repository.

Here is an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="target/generated-sources/xjc"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

It is important to note that some [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) plugins don't attach the generated sources to the POM. You can use the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to over come this.

Answer (score 8):

I never found a standard way to handle the resulting source files. However, based on my experience I would recommend you the following:

> - Where should I generate the .java source files? (src/main/java,
>     src/main/generated)

- I put them under src/main/com/mypackage/generated. This way, **they are already in the classpath and you will not need any other manual configuration** to have Eclipse compile without errors.

> - Should I include them under source control, or let them be generated after check-out

- I ***used to NOT include them***, but **after some issues** (developers not generating them because they forgot, lack of IDE Maven plugin, etc.) **we end up adding them to source control**. This **helped anyone know that there is a package of generated sources that didn't appear magically, quickly check schemas changes by just exploring a folder (some source files do not exist anymore, etc.) and see the real size of the app**.

> - If I don't use the src/main/java folder, how to convince Eclipse automatically to "see" those classes as source folder?

- **Solved by using src/main/com/mypackage/generated.**

> - Do I really need the .java files, or only the .class-es?

- I would suggest to use the .java files.

Just my two cents, after years of using JAXB, mainly for WSDL to Java generation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendation after many many years: **Put all your code generation in a separate maven project and depend on it in your normal projects that need the generated code.**

- Do a `mvn install` for your generated code if it is SNAPSHOT.
- Unless you know what you are doing I do not recommend putting the generated code in a submodule otherwise Eclipse will constantly get confused because most people import all submodules (ie multimodule project)
- *However* If you do decide to do multimodule (ie generated code is a sibling project) you can either:

  - Specifically not import the project into Eclipse and use `mvn install` on the individual project
  - Rely on m2e lifecycle plugins and Build Helper plugin (this only works well on certain code generation that is heavily supported).
- If you need to debug generated code I highly recommend attaching sources to the jar with the [maven-attach-sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) plugin.

While the multimodule approach seems like a good idea in practice it just becomes really freaking annoying because Eclipse will get out of sync every time you pull if there is a new SNAPSHOT.

If your generated code is not generated that often then just release it so it is not a SNAPSHOT (obviously this requires a proper maven repository being setup).